# Swagger codegen deserialize dynamic reponse

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

From my Java backend I'm consuming another backend which I don't manage and it's API definition is not available. I'm creating the OpenAPI definition of it's services and using Swagger Codegen to generate the client.

There is an endpoint which returns a complex object:

```
{
    "total": 151,
    "version": 4,
    "dynamicItem1": [
        "codeDynamicItem1",
        293,
        63700,
        19,
        "nameDynamicItem1",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        0,
        -64
    ],
    "dynamicItem2": [
        "codeDynamicItem2",
        237,
        40000,
        478,
        "nameDynamicItem2",
        "string1",
        "string2",
        "string3",
        0,
        0
    ]

}
```

In that object the `total` and `version` are always there but on the same level there are hundreds of those dynamic items. The key is predictable in the example above but in reality is a sequence of letter and numbers, something like "245df921". The dynamic items are always arrays with the same number of items and in the same expected positions.

To parse that object I'm using [additionalProperties](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/) beacuse I read that it's the right way to parse hashmaps, but seems like I'm not applying it correctly.

Currently my OpenAPI representation looks like this:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: title
  description: description
paths:
  /complexObject:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: "OK"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Object'
components:
  schemas:
    Object:
      type: object
      properties:
        total:
          type: number
          example: 151
        version:
          type: number
          example: 4
        additionalProperties:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            nullable: true
```

Using that implementation the `total` and `version` are returned properly but in the response object there is an `additionalProperties` attribute with null value.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`additionalProperties` needs to be on the same level as `properties`.

Also, since those dynamic array are multi-type (string / integer) you need `oneOf` to define possible item types.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Object:
      type: object
      properties:
        total:
          type: number
          example: 151
        version:
          type: number
          example: 4
      additionalProperties:   # <-----
        type: array
        items:
          oneOf:              # <-----
            - type: string
              nullable: true
            - type: integer
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but is not working because of this issue: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5187